# how can i multiply an element in $\mathbb{R}^5$ by an n x m matrix, and what would the outcome be?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c&d&e\\f&g&h&i&j\\l&m&n&o&p\end{bmatrix}$$
Let $T: \mathbb{R}^5\to \mathbb{R}^k$ be a linear transformation such that $T(x)=Ax$, then $k=$?

Comment: If you have a suggestion or a proposed edit, please state so in the comments and I will do my best, I hope it won't get downvoted as I'm studying for my finals and this is not an assignment by any means.

Comment: In this context, an element of $\Bbb R^5$ is a $5 \times 1$ matrix with entries in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: In whatever class / text / notes you're working from, be sure to understand the definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: I do understand matrix multiplication, however, this question states that the outcome would be in R^k

Comment: That is a five by three matrix so maps [math]R^5[/math] to [math]R^3[/math].

Comment: I tried multiplication and the outcome would be a 3*1 matrix, not in the R subspace if i understand this correctly.

Comment: so it's 1*3 not 3*1?

Comment: @GeorgeIvey The math syntax here is `$R^5$` to get $R^5$

Comment: @Anonymouss In linear algebra, we usually think of $k \times 1$ matrices as elements of $\Bbb R^k$; whether those things really are the same is more of a philosophical matter I suppose.

Comment: @Anonymouss What makes you say that we're implying the answer is $1 \times 3$? Is there a reason that you think of elements of $\Bbb R^3$ as row-vectors rather than as column-vectors?

Comment: @BenGrossmann so a 1*3 matrix is considered an element of $R^3$, and i get K=3 is that right?

Comment: @Anonymouss Yes

Comment: thank you, everyone, best interaction on this website so far, deepened my understanding of matrices and R spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help I got from people in the comments, I now understand that an element in $\mathbb{R}^5$ is considered a $5 \times 1$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{R}$, so the question gets simplified to basic matrix multiplication.
When we multiply an $n \times p$ matrix and a $p \times m$ matrix, the result is an $n\times m$ matrix, a $3 \times 1$ matrix in this case, so $k=3$.